# Javascript Running Order

Tags: javascript, function

Just a quick question. I wonder how javascript function runs if they're being called.

Example: I have this

```
function1();
function2();
function3();
function4();
function5();
```

I am calling these functions somewhere in my program. Does it run orderly based on what line they are called? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. **Executed** in order you've written.

Comment: run a test and find out...... `function function1(){ console.log(1); }` repeat.... run it....

Comment: @epascarello i did  that but someone told me that it is asynchonous or something.

Comment: If you're dealing with asynchronous behavior (eg: http requests, promises, async/await, `setImmediate`, `setTimeout`) that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Well those function calls will be synchronous, it does not mean what happens inside is....

Comment: Definitely true, but the difference between those two could be very easily lost on someone inexperienced with JS.